# Get Facebook Posts and Tweets to use on own app

Tags: facebook, api, twitter

I want to know if it is possible to get the Facebook Posts or Twitter Tweets from a user at the time that they are created/posted.

I know I can get the old posts/tweets from a certain user, but I need to get them when they are created. Otherwise I must check all the time to know if the user has posted or tweeted something.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

For twitter, see the [streaming api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/) - specifically user streams.

For facebook, there are [real-time updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/).

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook, you can have your HTML code subscribe to the http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/ on the "edge.create" which says a like happened.  Then you ajax to your server that the user liked it and you store that information in your database.

For Twitter, you can subscribe to events as well.  See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents